# sha1 collision of less than 512 bit

Tags: python, collision, sha1

In Wikipedia [SHA-1 pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), it's said:

> Pre-processing: append the bit '1' to the message e.g. by adding 0x80
>   if message length is a multiple of 8 bits. append 0 ≤ k < 512 bits
>   '0', such that the resulting message length in bits

So is it same with `\x01` and `x00\x01`?

Python example:

```
import hashlib
for s in ('01', '0001'):
    m=hashlib.sha1()
    m.update(s.decode('hex'))
    print m.hexdigest()

>>>bf8b4530d8d246dd74ac53a13471bba17941dff7
>>>0e356ba505631fbf715758bed27d503f8b260e3a
```

It turns out not to be the same, why?

Comment: `hashlib.sha1` is already a complete implementation of SHA-1. You don't need to preprocess anything.

Comment: i want to know if collision in less than 512 bit inputs

Answer (score 1):

**`\x01` and `\x0001` cannot be the same after pre-processing.**

I think that you misunderstand the pseudocode in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1). Here I take `\x01` and `\x0001` as examples, which their length are less than `512` bits.

(Now suppose that the original message length is less than `448` bits)

- first step: fill in to let its length **=448 (mod 512)**. We append the `1` bit first, then append `0`.

Thus, for `\x01`, it becomes `\x01800000...000`, and its length is 448 bits, and the ellipsis represents `0` in **hex**.

- second step: fill in the length. We should add the reminder `(512 - 448) = 64` bits to represent its original length.

Thus, for `\x01`, its original length is `8`, it shall append `\x00000000 00000008`.

From mentioned above, after pre-processing, `\x01` becomes `\x01800000...08`, and whole length is 512, and the ellipsis represents `0` in **hex**.

Comment: so in conclusion, shall we say that from '\x1' to any 100 TB length data, there's no collision found yet for 160bit sha1 digest now?